# issue in using Math.pow() function

Tags: java, android, math

```
            String loanamount = edtamount.getText().toString();
            double doubleloanamount = Double.parseDouble(loanamount);
            String strloanamount = Double.toString(doubleloanamount);

            Log.v("doubleloanamout", strloanamount);

            String years = edtyears.getText().toString();

            double doubleyears = Double.parseDouble(years) * 12;

            String strpaymentdoubleyears =   Double.toString(doubleyears);
            Log.v("doubleyears", strpaymentdoubleyears);

            double inrate = doubleloanamount * 11 / 100;
            double monthlyrate = inrate / 12;
            double roundmonthlyrate = Math.round(monthlyrate);
            String inratefordemo = Double.toString(roundmonthlyrate);


            double Payment = (doubleloanamount
                    * Math.pow(( roundmonthlyrate) + 1, (doubleyears)) *  roundmonthlyrate)
                    / (Math.pow( roundmonthlyrate + 1, (doubleyears)) - 1);



            double roundpayment = Math.round(Payment);
            String strpayment = Double.toString(roundpayment);
            Log.v("payment", strpayment);
            edtemimonth.setText(strpayment);
```

i am using above code for calculating EMI but it shows 0 value.hay i used both int and double still its it gives me 0 for int 0.0 for double

Comment: is doubleloanamount equal to zero? The issue could be related to the double/int cast you are performing or also to doubleloanamount value

Comment: I suspect `Math.round(monthlyrate)` is 0 unless you have over 50% interest per month which is exceedingly high. I suggest you step through your code with a debugger to see what each line of code does and the result you get.

Comment: hay i removed that Math.round() funtion still it shows 0 result

Answer (score 6):

Because you are type casting result into integer, may be it had a fraction part like 0.55 and due to type casting it has removed fraction part and giving only 0. Try changing Payment variable to double, also make sure `doubleloanamount` is not equal to 0.

Comment: see my edited part i used double in place of int still it gives me 0.0 output

Answer (score 0):

make intRate to float .... while calculation of payment intRate * X will give 0 if intRate itself is 0 . You have written intRate = x * 11/100 which if less than 1 will be 0.

Also make mnthRate to float